# How mount directory from docker volume?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have docker volume code and I would like map only one directory from this volume.

```
    volumes:
    - code:/var/www/html
```

Can I do that?

```
     volumes:
    - code/xxx:/var/www/html
```

Can I only use host_path?

Answer (score 0):

You can map the directory xxx inside /var/www/html directory inside the container

Try to use relative path:

volumes:

-./code/xxx:/var/www/html